# Playing Audio from a class in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

Okay, so I'm working on a game using SpriteKit, and there is background music throughout the app. Initially, I had just used a new `AVAudioPlayer` in each scene with the appropriate audio file, but now I am finding that I'd like to have uninterrupted audio playback when moving between menus and such. So I am attempting use a separate class to handle all of the background music. I'm not sure if this is technically possible, if not, I'd like to see if there's another way to solve my problem.

So onto the code... here's the header file for my audio class:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(int, songTitle) {
    Menu_Music,
    Level_1,
    Level_2,
    Game_Over,
};

@interface NWAudioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer

@property (nonatomic, assign) songTitle songName;
@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer* bgPlayer;

-(void)createAllMusicWithAudio: (songTitle)audio;

@end
```

and here's the implementation:

```
#import "NWAudioPlayer.h"

@implementation NWAudioPlayer

-(void)createAllMusicWithAudio: (songTitle)audio {

    if ([[GameState sharedGameData] audioWillPlay] == YES) {
        switch (audio) {
            case Menu_Music:
                [self playMusicWithString:@"menuMusic"];
                break;
            case Level_1:
                [self playMusicWithString:@"Level-1-Music"];
                break;
            case Level_2:
                [self playMusicWithString:@"Level-2-Music"];
                break;
            case Game_Over:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)playMusicWithString: (NSString *)file {
    NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"menuMusic" ofType:@"m4a"];
    NSURL *soundFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile];
    NSError *Error = nil;
    _bgPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileUrl error:&Error];
    _bgPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [_bgPlayer prepareToPlay];

    NSLog(soundFile);
}

@end
```

And then here's what I have in my scene's implementation:

```
-(void)createAudio
{
    [[NWAudioPlayer alloc] createAllMusicWithAudio:Menu_Music];
    [[NWAudioPlayer alloc].bgPlayer play];
}
```

and obviously I'll call `[self createAudio]` in the init for that scene.

The frustrating part is that I'm not getting a single error, and my NSLog is showing that the method is calling the correct audio file, but nothing is playing. Clearly I'm missing something... I'm stumped. Any help is appreciated! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the code that manages an `AVAudioPlayer` from the scene code. You could put it in your application delegate, for example, or create your own music player class with a singleton instance.

Comment: Okay, I'm not super familiar with using singletons, so excuse my ignorance. What would I do differently with my NSAudioPlayer class to make it a singleton instance, rather that whatever it is now?

Comment: Okay I think I figured it out. I have a basic singleton working anyway. Thanks for the pointer!